# Which houses have an Alchemy table WITH an Alchemy Satchel?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have one in my house in Whiterun, but was sad to find that my house in Solitude doesn't have a satchel.

Do any of the other available houses have this feature?

Comment: I don't own all the houses yet, so I'm not 100% sure but according to [notable house features](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Houses), the Whiterun house is the only one with the satchel on the table.

Comment: Yup its the only one. I ultimately settled for the house in Winterhold and use the wardrobe cabinet just outside the door to the tables. As soon as the construction set is released ill be giving solitude the upgrades it should have had. The house in whiterun has the satchel and a chest in the potion room. No other house has that! I don't know what they were thinking we wanted in a house when they created it.

Comment: Is the construction set only for PC?

Comment: Yes (12 chars)...

Comment: Lame (why sell a game for multiple platforms if one of them is going to give a far superior experience :( )

Comment: Bethesda games are ALWAYS better for PC because they are very modable - you can't really mod stuff for 360 or PS3 because those game console makers don't want you to. Also - the graphics are far superior on PC thanks to the Better Quality Textures you can run

Comment: Grats on hitting 1k rep!

Comment: Thanks! But I've already hit 1k rep 3 or 4 times now, I keep spending it all on bounties.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The alchemy lab in the Markarth house has one satchel plus two barrels, which can be used to store potions as well.

Answer (score 1):

With the steam workshop [Crafting Satchels mod](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=7438), all of them.